# How to detect API call from Zapier?

Tags: java, synchronization, zapier, zapier-cli

**Is there any way to detect API call from Zapier to my app?**

I've created two zaps on Zapier. Creating tasks from Wrike to MyApp and vice versa.

I got infinite loop, because when I create task on Wrike it is automatically created on MyApp. But than Zapier detects new task on MyApp and creates new one (same task) in Wrike and so on.

I was thinking to add new field in task object (createdFromZapier) and filter by that field, but is there any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is answer from *Zapier team*:**

There isn't a great way to do this — at best, you could set the User Agent header within your developer integration and then inspect the header on your API server side to detect when a request is coming from Zapier.

We have a help guide on avoiding Zap loops at https://zapier.com/help/troubleshoot/behavior/zap-is-stuck-in-a-loop which might help.